# Performing task only once per iteration in Fortran OpenMP code

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, nested-loops

I have a Fortran code that I am trying to parallelize with OpenMP, and I am a beginner. It consists of a nested loop, where the innermost loop is the largest and the most optimal target for parallelizing. An important variable `var` is defined in the smaller outer loop (index `i`) and used by all iterations in the inner loop (index `j`).

When parallelizing just the inner loop, I have observed that all available threads will not be used in the next outer iteration until all calculations of the inner loop are done, as expected. However, I predict this will be an inefficient use of computing time on the cluster. I want to allow the outer loop to go ahead and define the new `var` in the next `i` index and continue with the next `j` index while the previous `j` loop is finishing up. How would you recommend doing this?

For the inner loop treatment, I tried using the NOWAIT specifier, but that causes the outer loop to create `var` every time, which is just as inefficient. How can I direct the program to save `var` as data for every thread entering the new `i` index?

The following is an example of what I have now:

```
    program Test

    integer::i,j
    double precision::inp1(10) !array of unique input values
    double precision::val,output
    ...

!$OMP PARALLEL
!$OMP&DEFAULT(SHARED)
!$OMP&PRIVATE(val,output,i,j)

    do i=1,10 !small loop

        !create val just once and use in relevant j index
        call mysub1(inp1(i),val) 
        ...
 !$OMP DO
        do j=1,100000 !ton of iterations in this loop

            call mysub2(val,output)
            !do things with output 
            ...

        end do !for j

        !if threads are available, don't wait for j to finish 
        !and move on to next i iteration

!$OMP END DO NOWAIT
    end do !for i
!$OMP END PARALLEL

    ...

    end program

    subroutine mysub1(inp1,val)
      !(do things with inp1 and calculate val)
      ...
      return
    end subroutine

    subroutine mysub2(val,output)
      !(do things with val and create output)
      ...
      return
    end subroutine
```

I imagine the answer is simple, but I'm kind of lost right now! Do I use  `SINGLE` or `TASK` constructs around `mysub1`?

Comment: Do the `i` iterations depend on the previous iterations? Why is the `OMP DO` inside the `i` loop and not outside? It might be helpful to show the actual code that requires the choice you did.

Comment: And welcome at Stack Overflow, it will also be really useful to take the Welcome [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: How many threads will this code generally run on? If it's around the number of `i`-loops, it would probably be wiser to parallelize the `i`-loop

Comment: @VladimirF The `i` iterations are independent. The code is based off of an old f90 code with a lot of common blocks that was not meant to be thread safe, and I have to use critical labels around both subroutines to prevent segfaults. I've definitely made a version with the parallel do specified for the outer loop, but for some reason the huge inner loop ends up getting just one thread in the end.

Comment: @Fl.pf. The code will have 24 threads on hand. Given the hundred `i` iterations, each `i` basically gets its own thread. Since `var` is based on special material properties, the choice of `inp1(i)` can dramatically speed up the `j` loop, which is why I want to parallelize mainly the inner loop. I just want to use time effectively.